# Populate list of object using group by in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've the following classes

```
public class R
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int RNumber { get; set; }
    public int VNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RD
{
    public Guid RDId { get; set; }
}

public class RRDS
{
    public R R { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public List<RD> RDs{ get; set; }
}

public class RRSDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public int RNumber { get; set; }
    public int VNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid RDId { get; set; }
}
```

From the database i get the list of RRSDto. i need to convert the list of RRSDto to list of RRDS. The Id, Title, ProjectTile, RNumber, VNumber can be same but the RDId will be different.

This is what i've tried with LINQ:

```
var temp = (from r in rrs
            group r by new
            {
                r.Id,
                r.Title,
                r.ProjectTitle,
                r.RNumber,
                r.VNumber,
            } into gcs
            select new RRDS()
            {
                R = new R()
                {
                    Id = gcs.Key.Id,
                    Title = gcs.Key.Title,
                    RNumber = gcs.Key.RNumber,
                    VNumber = gcs.Key.VNumber
                },
                ProjectTitle = gcs.Key.ProjectTitle,
                RDs = new List<RD>()
                {
                    new RD()
                    {
                        RDId = gcs.ToList().Select(g =>  g.RDId).FirstOrDefault()
                    }
                }
            }).ToList();
```

Instead of FirstOrDefault i want the list of RDIds. How do i get it using LINQ?

Thanks in advance,
Suyog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the `RDId` then simply project them using *Select*, I don't see any reason to use *FirstOrDefault* since you are not looking for first `RDId` within the group:-

```
 ,RDs = gcs.Select(g => new RD { RDId = g.RDId }).ToList()
```